# What is the integral of 1/(z-i) over the unit circle?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

At present there is a simple pole *on* the closed contour, so the Residue Theorem appears to be inapplicable.

But I want to claim that we can enlarge this circle to make sure that it encloses the pole, and the integral value should not change, primarily because of Cauchy's Theorem.

So the integral is simply $2\pi i$. (The residue at $z=i$ is 1.)

What do you think?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the integral of $1/z$ over $z \in [-1,1]$?

Comment: Reminds me of how physicists deal with poles in their path. So we run a tiny circle above or below it and let go $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: @mvw Haha, oh yes...

Comment: @flawr, is the answer to your integral...infinity? Thanks,

Comment: Well it is a quite similar question to yours.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think your path should not run into a pole for a well defined curve integral. Doing a circumvention is possible but then it needs to include the direction $\pm \epsilon$ and means something related but still different.

Comment: Agreed, @mvw, but that was the question as stated...so it was definitely a little bit of a trap question ...

Comment: I'll revisit some material regarding deformation of paths...thanks @mvw,

Comment: If you shrink a little it is $0$.

Comment: Modifying the path changes the value of the integral; indeed, if we instead "shrank this circle" by some small amount instead---and a priori there's no reason why this should be any better than enlargement---one instead gets (via the Residue Theorem) a value of $0$ instead.

Comment: Right...by Cauchy's Thm @mvw ... hmmm....

Comment: Hi @Travis, do you think the question itself is then...incorrectly stated?  Thanks,

Comment: The physicist are not stupid, such solutions are used in a certain context where the extra info (here shrinked or enlarged) will lead to a proper answer.

Comment: @flawr, checking with wolfram...I think now that your integral and mine...are both equal to infinity... :-( what do you think?

Comment: Just to chip in: I agree with @flawr's example. If you hit a pole with your integral, there's not much you can do. Just like the real integral of 1/x, the result is *undefined*. If you use symmetric limits, the two infinite contributions kill each other, and you *could* get 0. Otherwise you could get any finite value for the integral. If you go down to the definition of the integral: `int_{-eps}^{eps} 1/x dx` just does not exist. You could still speak about its Cauchy principal value, which is 0.

Comment: Got it, @AndrasDeak, thanks so much.  Trick question.  So the answer is simply, "it is undefined."  :-(

Comment: (cont.) All the tricks distorting complex contours are based on the assumption that the integrand is analytical on the contour, and you never cross any poles while deforming the contour. I guess this just boils down to the fact that poles are localized divergence in analytical (holomorphic?) functions, and you can play around the contours fairly freely (but you can only walk through a pole by enclosing said contour in a bubble contour of opposite orientation.)

Comment: No, the question is not nonsense a priori, and in fact I think it's a good one. But it is certainly incorrect to say without qualification that the value is $2 \pi i$.

Comment: As for your last comment @User001, I would think so, yes. You *could* define some limit for it (maybe?), mainly something along the lines of a Cauchy principal value (or exactly that). But you'd have to be careful, and interpreting the result would need caution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contour integrals are the same as integrals in this respect: you can't simply stick a pole in their path of integration.  In this case, you can employ what is known as a Cauchy principal value of the contour integral, which excludes the pole.  This involves deforming the path of integration around the pole.  Whether you deform the path inside or outside the unit circle does not matter, as I will illustrate.

Normally, I deform inside the circle so as to exclude the pole; this is the contour $C$.  The integral over $C$ is zero by Cauchy's theorem.  In this case, the integral looks like

$$\oint_{C} \frac{dz}{z-i} = PV \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z-i} + i \epsilon \int_{2 \pi}^{\pi} \frac{d\phi \, e^{i \phi}}{i + \epsilon e^{i \phi} - i}  = 0$$

Thus,

$$PV \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z-i} = i \pi$$

On the other hand, if we use a contour $C'$ in which we include the pole, then the integral around $C'$ is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the integrand at the pole, which residue is simply $1$.  Thus,

$$\oint_{C'} \frac{dz}{z-i} = PV \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z-i} + i \epsilon \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{d\phi \, e^{i \phi}}{i + \epsilon e^{i \phi} - i}  = i 2 \pi$$

which produces the previous result.

Now, if you enlarge the circle so that you are no longer on the unit circle but on a circle of larger radius that encloses the pole at $z=i$, then, yes, the integral about that circle is indeed $i 2 \pi$.  Or if you shrink the circle so that the pole is outside the circle, the integral about that circle is zero.  But for the unit circle, on which the pole lies, the integral over the circle makes sense only when speaking of its Cauchy PV, which is $i \pi$.

Comment: If I understand correctly that your bottom line is $PV \oint ... = \imath\pi$, then this is not altogether clear from your answer (to me, at least).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: The integral over $\phi$ is equal to $i \pi$; subtract that form both sides to get the result.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out in the mean time (the unsimplified form of the semicircular deformations, while clearer to understand eventually, were distracting at first. Again: to me, at least.). I just had to be sure that the result is not on the left side, but the principal value (in agreement with the text, which I did read the first time:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: the result is indeed the PV.  But, as in many problems that employ Cauchy's theorem, you have to set up a different integration contour to get the answer you want.

Comment: Indeed, thanks again. It's just that after a lengthy discussion of whether the integral exists in the first place (see comments on question) I got a bit distracted.

Comment: Hi @RonGordon, sorry for the simple question, but is the final answer then...$2\pi i$ ...or $i\pi$?  Thanks so much,

Comment: (I am still thinking about your solution... and am trying to understand it, @RonGordon, thanks...)

Comment: The PV integral is the average of the integrals around the two contours $C$ and $C'$.  You might note that this method works only for simple poles on smooth contours.  For poles of higher order or at corners of contours, things are more complicated.

Comment: @User001: My point was that the PV is equal to $i \pi$ regardless os whether you used $C$ or $C'$.

Answer (score 4):

The integral does not converge. To show this in the most informative way, you should recall the definition of a contour integral: Let $\gamma(t)$ be a contour defined over $\mathbb{C}$ with $t\in I$. Then

\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma}{f(z)dz}:=\int_I{f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt}.
\end{align}

So applying this to the integral in question (I've missed out a bit of algebra), we get

\begin{align}
\oint_{S^1}\frac{1}{z-\imath}dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{\imath}{e^{\imath t}-\imath}}dt\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(t)-1+\imath\cos(t)}{1-2\sin(t)}dt.
\end{align}
Now, one can (after a little work) compute that
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sin(t)-1+\imath\cos(t)}{1-2\sin(t)}dt=\frac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\imath}{2}\log(1-2\sin(t))+z_0.
\end{align}

This function is undefined at both $0$ and $2\pi$ and hence the integral has no limit, or formally it diverges.